# How can to filter to display only sales for transactions that belong to logged in user in django framework class based view

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

class based view

```
class SaleListView(ListView):
    model = Sale
    template_name = 'webapp/sale.html'
    context_object_name = 'sales'
```

transaction model - a user can have many transactions

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    date_purchased = models.DateTimeField()
    note = models.TextField(default="")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

sale model - a transaction can have many sales

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    amount_sold = models.IntegerField()
    total_price_sold = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    date_sold = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    note = models.TextField(default="")
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `get_queryset` method to update the queryset

```
class SaleListView(ListView):
    model = Sale
    template_name = 'webapp/sale.html'
    context_object_name = 'sales'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = self.model.objects.filter(transaction__owner=self.request.user)
        return qs
```

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering)

Answer (score 0):

We can filter the queryset like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class SaleListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Sale
    template_name = 'webapp/sale.html'
    context_object_name = 'sales'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(transaction__owner=self.request.user)
```

We here thus filter the queryset such that we only obtain `Sale`s for which the related `transaction` has an `owner` that is `self.request.user`: the logged in user.

The `LoginRequiredMixin` is useful such that one can not acces the given view if he/she is not logged in. In that case the system will return a redirect to the login page (or another page if you specify that).